# Проблема с изображением SWF

Tags: actionscript

Всем привет! Копаюсь в файлах игры, чисто по фану, в программировании, скажу сразу, чисто 0.
Проблема такая, что отображаются иконки , в тех местах где по идеи они не должны отображаться.

Вот изображение:
[image: Если в коде изменить начальную страницу, то этих изображений нет, но при перелистывании они появляются]

```
    function getLicense()
{
   if(myroot.license == 1)
   {
      for(var _loc4_ in _root.BoxList)
      {
         if(Math.floor(_root.BoxList[_loc4_].type) == 778)
         {
            pasp = _root.BoxList[_loc4_].res;
         }
      }
      if(pasp != myroot.sv)
      {
         com.timezero.game.display.gui.window.message.MessageBox.alert(_global.LANG.mr_notacitizen);
         return undefined;
      }
   }
   if(_root.USER.level < MinLevel)
   {
      com.timezero.game.display.gui.window.message.MessageBox.alert(_root.SearchReplace(LANG.mr_err10,MinLevel));
      return undefined;
   }
   if(myroot.mr.tkPage > 0)
   {
      myroot.mr.Close();
      return undefined;
   }
   if(!lic_list)
   {
      xml_lic();
   }
   myroot.mr.Close();
   this.lockInterface();
   myroot.news._visible = false;
   var _loc5_ = myroot.attachMovie("License","mr",myroot.getNextHighestDepth(),{_x:20,_y:25});
   myroot.holder.swapDepths(myroot.getNextHighestDepth());
   _loc5_.icons = new Array("cityhall");
   _root.createBorder(_loc5_.bg,-600,{close:_loc5_,dragBounds:_loc5_.bg});
   _loc5_.bg_icon.swapDepths(-401);
   _root.createBorder(_loc5_.bg_icon,-400);
   _global.Box.prototype.UpdateIcon.call(_loc5_);
   _loc5_.tkPage = 1;
   _loc5_.page_btn.b1.onRelease = function()
   {
      var _loc3_ = this._parent._parent;
      if(_loc3_.tkPage > 1)
      {
         if(_root.ShiftPressed())
         {
            _loc3_.tkPage = 1;
         }
         else
         {
            _loc3_.tkPage -= 1;
         }
         _loc3_.Update();
      }
   };
   _loc5_.page_btn.b2.onRelease = function()
   {
      var _loc3_ = this._parent._parent;
      var _loc4_ = Math.ceil(lic_list.length / 4);
      if(_loc3_.tkPage < _loc4_)
      {
         if(_root.ShiftPressed())
         {
            _loc3_.tkPage = _loc4_;
         }
         else
         {
            _loc3_.tkPage += 1;
         }
         _loc3_.Update();
      }
   };
   _loc5_.Update = function()
   {
      if(!lic_list)
      {
         this._visible = false;
      }
      else if(!lic_list.length)
      {
         com.timezero.game.display.gui.window.message.MessageBox.alert(LANG.mr_err8);
         this.Close();
      }
      else
      {
         var _loc4_ = _root.CheckBuildMaster();
         this._visible = true;
         this.page_btn.label.ftext(this.tkPage + "/" + Math.ceil(lic_list.length / 4));
         var _loc5_ = undefined;
         var _loc6_ = undefined;
         var _loc7_ = 0;
         while(_loc7_ < 4)
         {
            _loc5_ = lic_list[(this.tkPage - 1) * 4 + _loc7_];
            _loc6_ = this["l" + (_loc7_ + 1)];
            if(_loc5_.mc)
            {
               _loc5_.mc.removeMovieClip();
            }
            if(!_loc5_ || !_loc5_.count)
            {
               _loc6_._visible = false;
            }
            else
            {
               _loc6_.__item = _loc5_;
               _loc6_._visible = true;
               _loc6_.title.ftext(_loc5_.txt);
               _loc6_.cost.ftext(LANG.cost + ": " + (_loc5_.cost || 0));
               _loc6_.dsc.htmlText = "" + (!_loc5_.OD ? "" : _root.SearchReplace(LANG.mr_tm,_loc5_.OD) + "<br />") + "<u>" + _loc5_.hint + "</u><br /> ";
               _loc6_.dsc.setTextFormat(_global.myTextFormat);
               if(_loc4_)
               {
                  _loc6_.btn_chg._visible = false;
                  _loc6_.cost._x = 0;
                  _root.setHint(_loc6_.btn_chg,_root.SearchReplace(LANG.sh_chg,_loc5_.txt));
                  _loc6_.btn_chg.onRelease = function()
                  {
                     var _loc3_ = this._parent;
                     _root.UpPadding("WinDrop","WinDrop").Init(_root.SearchReplace(LANG.mr_ch,_loc3_.__item.txt,_loc3_.__item.cost2),LANG.CHANGE,_loc3_,"doChg",0,9999,_loc3_.__item.cost,LANG.money);
                  };
               }
               else
               {
                  _loc6_.btn_chg._visible = false;
                  _loc6_.cost._x = 0;
               }
               _loc6_.btn_buy.label.ftext(LANG.buy);
               _root.setHint(_loc6_.btn_buy,_root.SearchReplace(LANG.sh_buy,_loc5_.txt));
               _loc6_.btn_buy.onRelease = function()
               {
                  var _loc3_ = this._parent;
                  if(!_loc3_.__item.cost)
                  {
                     com.timezero.game.display.gui.window.message.MessageBox.alert(LANG.mr_err9);
                  }
                  else
                  {
                     _root.UpPadding("WinDrop","WinDrop").Init(_root.SearchReplace(LANG.sh_buy,_loc3_.__item.txt),LANG.buy,_loc3_,"doBuy",1,_loc3_.__item.OD <= 0 ? _loc3_.__item.count : undefined,1);
                  }
               };
               _loc6_.drawImage = DrawImage;
               _loc6_.drawImage();
            }
            _loc6_.doChg = function(cost)
            {
               if(cost > 0 && cost < this.__item.cost2)
               {
                  com.timezero.game.display.gui.window.message.MessageBox.alert(LANG.mr_err7);
               }
               else
               {
                  xml_doChg(this.__item.id,this.__item.cost = cost);
                  this.cost.ftext(LANG.cost + ": " + cost);
               }
            };
            _loc6_.doBuy = function(count)
            {
               try_pay = 3;
               xml_doPay(try_pay_id = this.__item.id,count);
            };
            _loc7_ += 1;
         }
      }
   };
   _loc5_.Close = function()
   {
      this._parent.unlockInterface();
      for(var _loc2_ in lic_list)
      {
         lic_list[_loc2_].mc.removeMovieClip();
         delete lic_list[_loc2_].mc;
      }
      myroot.news._visible = true;
      this.removeMovieClip();
   };
   this.page_btn.label.ftext("");
   _loc5_.Update();
}
function SetLic(list)
{
   lic_list = list;
   var _loc2_ = 0;
   while(_loc2_ < lic_list.length)
   {
      if(lic_list[_loc2_].count <= 0)
      {
         _loc2_;
         _loc2_;
         lic_list.splice(_loc2_--,1);
      }
      _loc2_ += 1;
   }
   myroot.mr.Update();
}
function DrawImage()
{
   var _loc3_ = this.__item;
   var _loc4_ = false;
   if(_root.LoadLib(_loc3_.category,myroot.holder,this._parent,"Update"))
   {
      _loc4_ = true;
   }
   if(_loc4_)
   {
      this.createTextField("loading",3,0,30,80,20);
      this.loading.text = "loading...";
      return undefined;
   }
   this.loading.removeTextField();
   var _loc5_ = _root.DrawBigWeapon_mc(myroot.holder,_loc3_,80,80);
   var _loc6_ = this._x + this._parent._x;
   var _loc7_ = this._y + this._parent._y;
   _loc5_._x += _loc6_ + 40;
   _loc5_._y += _loc7_ + 40;
   _loc3_.mc = _loc5_;
}
```

Подскажите в каком направлении копать, понимаю, что:
1- Либо картинка не стоит в коде, который отвечает за скрытие элементов.
2- Картинка не связана с кодом, который отвечает за скрытие картинки.